# Can't catch error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, try-catch

I'm having trouble catching an error coming from a built-in function in matlab

Whenever I get an incorrect xml format the command history prints "fatal error" in my command windows. I'm trying to catch the error and keep it in a variable to stop it from printing out but it's not working!

```
try
    main=xmlread(ABSPATH);
catch er
    return
end
```

"[Fatal Error] DatasetInfo.xml:852:1: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

Is there away to stop this from printing?

Comment: Is your problem only the printing? If yes, please edit the title, since you do catch the error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you do catch the error, but you just need the error message to not appear.

You can achieve it with `evalc`, which evaluates an expression and captures the output:

```
[~, main] = evalc(sprintf('xmlread(%s)',ABSPATH));
```

**EDIT**
I am afraid it won't work, since, as written in the documentation:

> anything that would normally be written to the command window, except
>   for error messages, is captured and returned